# Jupyter display HTML file inside HTML file

Tags: python, html, jupyter-notebook

I want to display an HTML file that will reference another HTML file in the jupyter notebook, but it always shows me nothing.

[image]

Jupyter server logs in the below, and it seems like that server can get the file but failed to display it in the notebook.

```
[I 02:03:50.913 NotebookApp] 302 GET /notebooks/jupyter/46d2a8592dea2144603db52b9e9ee88d/input.html (::1) 1.020000ms
[I 02:03:50.970 NotebookApp] 302 GET /files/jupyter/46d2a8592dea2144603db52b9e9ee88d/output.html (::1) 0.480000ms
[W 02:03:51.020 NotebookApp] Forbidden
[W 02:03:51.021 NotebookApp] 403 POST /api/security/csp-report (::1) 0.680000ms referer=None
```

```py
from IPython.display import HTML, IFrame, display
iframe = f'<iframe src="default.html" width=100% height=400></iframe> '
display(HTML(iframe))
```

The content of default.html is like below:

```
<iframe src="output.html" width=100% height=400></iframe>
```

How do I successfully load another HTML file inside my jupyter notebook?

Answer (score 2):

Be sure you have a good online site for testing with.

This works for me in both the classic Jupyter notebook interface and in JupyterLab (Version 3.2.8) served via MyBinder.org (launch [by clicking here](https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/binder-examples/jupyterlab/master?urlpath=lab/tree/index.ipynb)) just now:

```py
import IPython
url = "https://jupyter.org"
iframe = '<iframe src=' + url + ' width=700 height=350></iframe>'
IPython.display.HTML(iframe)
```

It'll complain about the syntax for now yet still works.

Your code works with that site (and doesn't complain):

```py
from IPython.display import HTML, IFrame, display
iframe = f'<iframe src="https://jupyter.org" width=100% height=400></iframe> '
display(HTML(iframe))
```

If you are seeing an issue with accessing a local file then that isn't a problem with Jupyter. It is a browser security issue. Browsers don't allow that for security concerns, see 
[abdusco's comment
here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/201208/why-do-browsers-disallow-accessing-files-from-local-file-system-even-if-the-html) and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1454609/cannot-open-local-html-files-with-google-chrome).
I don't know if adding the `--allow-file-access-from-file` flag is possible since you don't provide how you launch your notebook or mention what browser you are using?

---

---

A simpler variation presently works in the classic notebook interface , **not JupyterLab**:

```py
from IPython.display import IFrame; IFrame('http://jupyter.org', width='100%', height=350)
```

Comment: Thanks for your clear answer, but I want to load local files. Using HTTP to load the file works for me too.

Answer (score 0):

It should be simply

```
from IPython.display import IFrame
IFrame("your.html", width=800, height=450)
```

Of course the path must be correct and file must be readable.