# Is it possible to display html file in .ipynb file without showing its code?

Tags: html, jupyter-notebook

I want to display html file in .ipynb notebook, but I could not find proper way to do it.

I found ways where you can display html from running its code with cell type "code", but I want to display it with cell type "markdown" so its code will not be visible. Is there any way to do so?

Comment: I read this differently than Marc S. I thought you were trying to display an HTML file within markdown within a running Jupyter notebook file? Can you confirm? I think the use of "show its code" and "running its code" and "so its code will not be visible" are confusing? I think by 'its', you just mean you don't want code used to display the HTML file showing, right? Like you want to avoid displaying the stuff like in code blocks [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71887684/8508004)? The 'its' is confusing specially since you can embed HTML code in a markdown cell. I think the big question ...

Comment: <continued> is since you don't want to use code to display an HTML file and instead want to be within a markdown cell and display an HTML file, what is your real end need? If you just need an image of the HTML file, you can make an image of it and use markdown to display the image inside markdown and make that a link to the page?  I forgot to mention about the 'its' being confusing is that one way to read what you wrote in the title is that the 'its' refers to the HTML file. The 'its' in the title isn't referencing anything actually written there if I think you are trying to do what I think.

Comment: I forgot to add that part of the big question is how and where you plan to share this that you don't want code displaying? There's so many options to how to accomplish what you describe, such as the route Marc S. suggests to display the notebook online using Voila that won't show the code cells at all or just editing out the code block in the HTML produced from the file, that it is hard to advise without more information about end result needed and scale, etc..

Comment: I use .ipynb notebooks to give class/home works: there are instructions and start code. Also there are web pages in some cases. So I want to display those web pages in "markdown" cells but not in "code" cells. For now I could display them with "code" cells with the following code: `%%html \n <iframe src="..." ...>`. I tried this code in "markdown" cell without `%%html` but it didn't work. Do you know the reason of it and could you tell me?

Comment: Are they opening the notebooks in active form in Jupyter when they are seeing the class work or homework? And if so, are you using JupyterLab? If you are using JupyterLab you can still use code but you'd  toggle to hide the code for that input cell. JupyterLab will respect the hidden nature when it reopens the notebook. Then you have markdown cells above and below that code cell. That's going to be the best option besides what I already suggested that you make a picture of the page and embed that image as a hyperlink in the makdown using standard markdown syntax to put images in markdown.

Answer (score 0):

I use the voila package to generate my html pages and I mix code cells and markdown cells for the text. The html pages contain only graphs, tables and comments but no code.
[example](https://emma-claire-mccarthy.medium.com/using-voil%C3%A0-to-turn-your-jupyter-notebook-into-a-web-application-90988524315b)